# Objetos suicidas ¿Causan comportamiento indefinido?

Tags: c++, ciclo-de-vida, comportamiento-indefinido

Tengo una máquina de estados que permite apilar estados (`Push`) y reemplazar estados (`Replace`). Cuando un estado es reemplazado, se elimina el estado anterior y se crea el nuevo en su lugar, la máquina de estados simplificada tiene las siguientes funciones:

```
struct B
{
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

using ptr = std::unique_ptr<B>;
using stack = std::list<ptr>;

stack s;

template <typename T>
void Push()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B, T>, "Error");
    s.emplace_back(new T);
}

template <typename T>
void Replace()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B, T>, "Error");
    s.back().reset(new T);
}

void f()
{
    (*s.back()).f();
}
```

Suponiendo los siguientes estados:

```
#define NOMBRE std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct D1 : public B
{
    D1() { NOMBRE; }
    ~D1() { NOMBRE; }
    void f() override {}
};

struct D2 : public B
{
    D2() { NOMBRE; }
    ~D2() { NOMBRE; }
    void f() override { Replace<D1>(); }
};
```

Vemos que cuando se llama a la función `B::f` sobre el estado `D2`, éste se *suicida* forzando ser reemplazado por el estado `D1`, éste código:

```
int main()
{
    Push<D1>();
    Replace<D2>();
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Genera la siguiente salida:

> 1. `D1::D1()`
> 2. `D2::D2()`
> 3. `virtual D1::~D1()`
> 4. `D1::D1()`
> 5. `virtual D2::~D2()`
> 6. `virtual D1::~D1()`

La salida se corresponde con las instrucciones de `main`:

---

1

`Push<D1>();`: Añade el estado `D1`.

2 y 3

`Replace<D2>()`: Reemplaza el estado actual (`D1`) con el estado `D2`: Primero se construye `D2` (paso 2) y luego se destruye `D1` (paso 3).

4 y 5

`f();`: Llama a la función `f` del estado actual (`D2`), este estado pide su *suicidio* al forzar ser reemplazado por el estado `D1`, por lo tanto se construye `D1` y acto seguido **se destruye `D2` ¡mientras la función `D2::f` estaba en ejecución!**.

6

`return 0;`: Se destruye `D1` al finalizar el programa.

---

Podéis ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l605lPMW9t2aUlyw).

#### Pregunta.

¿Es comportamiento indefinido que `D2` sea destruido **antes** de finalizar la ejecución de `D2::f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es comportamiento indefinido que D2 sea destruido antes de finalizar la ejecución de D2::f?

El comportamiento es totalmente el esperado y funcionará bien mientras se cumplan ciertas restricciones:

- no se puede acceder a miembros (variables o métodos) después de la llamada a `Replace`. Esto provocará acceso a memoria liberada.
- no se debe llamar a implementaciones de `f` de la clase padre. Esta restricción podría formar parte del punto anterior, pero me parece adecuado destacarlo.

Si se cumplen esas restricciones el programa va a funcionar y esto es debido a cómo se codifican las instrucciones en ensamblador.

La función es independiente de la instancia sobre la que se ejecuta, es decir, solo existe una función `f` para todos los objetos de tipo `D2`. Para que esto sea así, la función `f` recibe de forma implícita un puntero a la instancia de la clase. Es decir, las funciones no se crean ni se destruyen junto a los objetos... siempre están ahí.

Por otro lado, para que el sistema sepa retornar de una función lo único que necesita es encontrar en la pila un puntero a otra región de código. Este valor se carga en la pila de forma automática la llamar a la función y es un valor que es independiente de si los objetos se crean o se destruyen.

Dicho esto, mientras `f` no acceda de forma explícita a algún valor ubicado en la región de memoria liberada su ejecución será segura.